# Ubuntu 16.10 - fresh install, Can't Launch VMs in VirtualBox

Tags: kernel, 16.10

I'm unable to launch VMs that previously worked or create new VMs.

I get the same error and the suggested fix by VirtualBox doesn't work:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine MythUbuntu.

The virtual machine 'MythUbuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0
```

The application tells me to run `/sbin/vboxconfig` as root but that doesn't resolve the issue or complete successfully:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxdrv.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxdrv.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxballoonctrl-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxballoonctrl-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxautostart-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxautostart-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxweb-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

Without a specific to apply to *dmesg* I get the full system dump with:

```
dmesg | grep vbox

dmesg | grep virtualbox
```

These commands provide no output.

Is VB just not playing ball with 16.10 yet?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.